# Compatibility issue with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am new to work with Microsoft technologies. I have installed VS2010 in standard mode on my PC. But When I try to install Microsoft SQL management studio 2008, it throws a compatibility issue. My questions are,

1) Should I install later version of SQL management studio?
2) Should I move to VS 2008 or earlier?
3) Do I have to install another software to undergo the compatibility issue?
I am using windows8 OS.

Comment: What is the exact error message? It talks about incompatibility with Visual Studio or about incompatibility with Sql Server Express 2005 ?

Comment: In a popup window it appears as "This program has compatibility issues". This error is with the SQL management studio 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that is a message that comes from the OS. You could try to install and then update to a newer Service Pack or just download the latest SP for SQL Server Management Studio.
The issue has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

[Here you could find the latest Service Pack for Sql Server Management Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14630)

Comment: Thank you Steve. I have to ask another question due to lack of knowledge on this. Does the sql service pack(specified in your link) compatible with the .net framework 4? because vs2010 has .net framework 4 in it.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem.